# Showing $|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(kx)}k|<2\sqrt{\pi}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, inequality, summation, trigonometric-series

For any real $x$ and positive integer $n$, is it true that:

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(kx)}k\right|<2\sqrt{\pi}\quad ?$$

Please justify.

Comment: For $x \in (0,2\pi)$, you could write it as $\int_0^x \sum_{k=1}^n \cos(kt)dt$. Not sure, but this might help.

Comment: I was thinking about this too. But the integral is kinda messy after you sum the cosines.

Comment: [The best it is possible to state is:
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin(nx)}{n}\right|\leq\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x}\,dx = 1.85194\ldots$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493368/for-any-x-in-mathbb-r-and-any-positive-integer-n-is-left-sum-k-1n#493587).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

The sum inside the absolute value is the partial sum of the Fourier series of:

$$y = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{x}{2}$$
Gibbs phenomenon tells you that the maximum value of the sum is:
$$f(0_+) + \pi\cdot0.08949 = \frac{\pi}{2}+0.08949\pi\sim1.85<2\ll2\sqrt{\pi}$$
So, $2\sqrt{\pi}$ is a very loose bound.

Comment: ... a partial sum of the Fourier series of ..., you mean.

Comment: @RobertIsrael - but of course :) fixed.

Comment: Interesting. Too bad I don't know too much about Fourier series. Is there a more elementary approach?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it. $|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(kx)}k|$ is a partial sum of the Fourier series of the function $y=\frac{\pi-|x|}{2}$. Here are the sums for $n$=15 (gold) and $n$=1350 (green) along with the graph of $y=2\sqrt{\pi}$ (blue). Maybe this will help? The Gibbs effect seems to be the only thing that moves the sum anywhere towards $2\sqrt{\pi}$, but does so ever so slightly.

[image]